# Is there an option to pull metadata on urn:li[pivot][code]

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using the endpoint 'adAnalyticsV2' and when applying a pivot to the request I get a field named 'pivotvalue' and in the case of the pivot of: 'MEMBER_INDUSTRY'.

An example of a value in the 'pivotvalue' field is: 'urn:li:industry:50' Documentation here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/ads/ads-reporting

Is it possible to pull metadata about the 'urn:li:industry:50' value?

Looking at the reference table here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/reference/industry-codes I can discern that an Industry Code of 50 is 'Architecture & Planning'.

Is there a way to get this value from the adAnalyticsV2 endpoint?

My current solution is basically to copy the reference table and do a mapping to my data which is very clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is parsing the ids out of the pivotValues, get all of the industries for the endpoint: 
`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/industries`, and then mapping the industry names from the response to the ids.

Answer (score 2):

I found one option using response decoration (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/concepts/decoration), but it's not working for all **pivots***.

Try adding

```
projection=(*,elements(*(*,pivotValue~(*))))
```

or (for multiple pivots)

```
projection=(*,elements*(*,pivotValues(*~(*))))
```

You will get metadata for that pivotValue.
I have tested all pivots and get errors for **pivots*** bellow:

- CAMPAIGN_GROUP -> Unsupported URN domain: li:sponsoredCampaignGroup
- CREATIVE -> Downstream service returned an empty response for URN
- CONVERSION -> Unsupported URN domain:
  lla:llaPartnerConversion
- SERVING_LOCATION -> Malformed URN link:ON_SITE
- MEMBER_COMPANY_SIZE -> Malformed URN link: SIZE_11_TO_50
- MEMBER_COUNTRY -> Not enough permissions to access: GET /countriesV2

Other pivotValues seems to be fine.

Regards, Aleksander

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue :(

It's actually not possible to get all values because it's impossible to store all targeting options into our database (huge amount of members...companies...). We have tried using "Discover Targeting Options by URNs" (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/ads/ads-targeting1#entities4) but we always get an error (only for this endpoint).

@LinkedinDevelopers - It would be more elegant if we get more metadata for pivot values.

Regards, Aleksander

Comment: This does not provide an answer for the question. You should move it into comment section.